# android phone won't have 2 dev apps on it at once

Tags: android

i'm developing a couple of apps at the moment one is an image-processing app, the other a google maps app. when i'm developing them i can only have one app at a time on the phone. is there any reason for this? my phone is a Samsung galaxy portal api2.1.

i'd like to have a few apps on my phone that are in the development process for interview purposes. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just low on internal space so the second app doesn't fit? There shouldn't be any restriction of this sort.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen hi, how can i check this?

Comment: @MichaelMadsen i've just gone into sd card and phone storage settings. total space = 0.92GB, available space = 839MB, available space = 74.04MB(internal phone storage)

Comment: are the package names different?

Comment: @BillGary hi, no the package names are the same

Comment: @turtleboy: Well, there's your problem - package names have to be unique. As long as they have the same name, Android will consider them to be the same app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason can be that the applications share the same package name. Android uses the package name to distinguish which application to launch (using the launcher or startActivity calls). Is there a reason for you to have the same package name for different applications?

Comment: erm no not really:) i'll try change the package name through eclipse. thanks

Comment: no luck. i've renamed the package in one of the apps but still only one will install

Comment: You have to change it in the Android Manifest file and in all the class files, every instance of it.

Comment: @bill gary ok, i've just renamed it in the manifest. both apps now install but when i run the app whose package i've renamed, it give a classNotFoundException

Comment: you need to change every instance of the old packagename to the new one, in manifest, intent calls in the code, etc. easiest way is to hit <ctrl>-f and use the find/replace on every class file and the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall both apps on the device. Then after renaming the package names (all instances of them), run both again and it should work.